# How to correctly display messages in console?

Tags: perl, utf-8, mojolicious

I use mojolicious application. When I do logging all if fine, except when I run application under morbo I see text like:

```
$app->log->info('тест лога');
[Sat Oct  6 15:22:43 2018] [info] Ñ�ÐµÑ�Ñ� Ð»Ð¾Ð³Ð°
```

here is some problem with utf8.

**What should I do that messages will be correctly displayed?**

My terminal have support for utf8. I run Linux Mint v19.3

Here is how messages looks which come from script:
[image]

Test terminal:
[image]

Comment: You did not specify what OS you run the script under. Perhaps you use MS Windows not localized for Russia. In such case you need issue in terminal `chcp 65001` to switch code page to support UTF-8.

Comment: I use Linux Mint v19.3

Comment: If you `cat some_file` with 'тест лога' in terminal does it printed in readable form? Just to confirm that terminal _tuned_ for UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, it is readable.

Comment: Perhaps **mojo** by default is not set for UTF-8 output. Try to add at begin of main file `binmode STDOUT, ':encodin(UTF-8)'`.  Note: log facility can be using _STDERR_ if previous line do not help - [binmode FILEHANDLE, LAYER](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode)

Comment: `:encoding`, not `:encodin`, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run following code sample in your system. The test confirmed with correct *UTF-8* output in terminal

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Mojolicious::Lite -signatures;

get '/' => sub ($c) {
  $c->render(text => 'Hello World!');
};

app->log->info('тест лога');
app->start;
```

Run as `morbo test.pl` produces following output

```
:u99257852:~/work/perl/mojo$ morbo ./test.pl
Web application available at http://127.0.0.1:3000
[2020-10-31 13:33:57.42056] [83940] [info] тест лога
[2020-10-31 13:35:16.72465] [83940] [debug] [hga9Tgyy] GET "/"
[2020-10-31 13:35:16.72528] [83940] [debug] [hga9Tgyy] Routing to a callback
[2020-10-31 13:35:16.72574] [83940] [debug] [hga9Tgyy] 200 OK (0.001078s, 927.644/s)
(uiserver):u99257852:~/work/perl/mojo$
```

Tested locally with `nc localhost 3000`

```
(uiserver):u99257852:~$ nc localhost 3000
GET / HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 31 Oct 2020 17:35:16 GMT
Server: Mojolicious (Perl)
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 12

Hello World!
```

Output of `uname -a`

```
(uiserver):u99257852:~/work/perl/mojo$ uname -a
Linux infongwp-us19 4.4.223-icpu-044 #2 SMP Sun May 10 11:26:44 UTC 2020 x86_64 GNU/Linux
(uiserver):u99257852:~/work/perl/mojo$
```

*Bash* is user's shell configured with `~/.bashrc` with following settings to support *UTF-8*

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8:
```

Comment: Thank you for hint about binmode. I found the problem. I will post that at different answer, but probably we need to merge that into your one

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the following when using Mojo::Log to write to STDERR:

```perl
binmode STDERR, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

---

Mojo::Log explicitly encodes everything it logs using UTF-8, even when writing to STDERR.

```perl
sub append {
  my ($self, $msg) = @_;
 
  return unless my $handle = $self->handle;
  flock $handle, LOCK_EX;
  $handle->print(encode('UTF-8', $msg)) or croak "Can't write to log: $!";
  flock $handle, LOCK_UN;
}
```

When using STDERR as the log output (the default), this conflicts with the well-established practice of adding an encoding layer to STD*. In such a circumstance, double-encoding occurs.

One must therefore avoid doing

```perl
binmode STDERR, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

Note that this is done as part of

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```